# VBA update autofilter on all sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to find some simple VBA code to run auto filters on a all sheets
when i change any data on my central data page.

all the filters i want to update are on a separate sheet to the data that is being referenced in lookup tables.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what problem(s) have you encountered?

Comment: HI , Ive gotten as far as getting the first table table to work

my main data page is called "Truss Jobs and Delivery" i have the below
code in the module for Truss jobs and delivery, i have atleast 6 - 10 other filters on my sheet named template that i need to somehow make the autofilters update on. 
i have tried simply listing the additional table objects with no success. 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").ListObjects("Table2")
         .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
End Sub

Comment: I mean to say there are 6 - 10 other tables on sheet "Template" that I need to refresh autofilters for. 

PS. Thanks for the help :)